# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object when updating choice field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

model:

```
StatusChoices = (
    ("TODO", "todo"),
    ("DOING", "doing"),
    ("DONE", "done"),
)

class Task(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=StatusChoices,
        default=StatusChoices[0],
        max_length=5,
    )
```

request body:

```
{
    "id": 15,  
    "content": "Updated Task Content",
    "creationDate": "2020-10-23",
    "user": 2 ,
    "status": "DONE"
}
```

serialiser:

```
class TaskUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ("status")
```

view

```
class TaskUpdateAPIView(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, pk):
        try:
            task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        serializer = TaskUpdateSerializer(task, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            task.status = request.data.get("status", task.status)
            task.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("task/update/<int:pk>", 
        TaskUpdateAPIView.as_view(), 
        name='update-task'
        ),
]
```

New error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you share `views` and `urls`?

Comment: Good catch. Updating with changed error message

Comment: @Niko Updated the question

Comment: sorry for the late response and for not being able to help any further. Although if you have a repo I can take a look ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this code that I didn't include in the question...

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.status == "DONE":
        self.completionDate = timezone.now().date()
        self.save()
```

Comment: I see. I assume you already fixed it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Silly me

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and I could not reproduce the error, it works fine (with one exception on the serializer explained below). So, the `RecursionError` must be somewhere else, hard to say exactly without some more code. That aside, I do have a few inputs.

By making use of Django built-in shortcut [get-object-or-404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) and [raise_exception](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data) flag you can clean your code. Also, fall back on the `serializer` to update the object instance instead of doing it manually. Alternatively, you can use the concrete [`UpdateAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview) which does exactly the same:

```py
class TaskUpdateAPIView(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, pk):
        task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
        serializer = TaskUpdateSerializer(task, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The serializer `fields` must be a tuple or list. So, either transform it into a list `[...]` or into a tuple by adding a `,` after the first element. (That was the only error)

```py
class TaskUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('status',)
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I didn't add part of code that was breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the `fields` value within the Serializer. In fact, when you define a string inside parentheses it's still a string:

```py
In [1]: type(("status"))
Out[1]: str
```

Therefore, the serializer iterates over each letter of the "status" and most likely leads to recursion error by python!

On the other hand, you must define a `list` or a `tuple` as a value for the `fields` instead. So you can simply add a comma after `status` to make it a `tuple`:

```py
In [2]: type(("status",))
Out[2]: tuple
```